# How to use Inferred Indexable Types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Take this code for example:

```
function<T, typeA = T['foo'], typeB = typeA>({
  foo,
  bar
} :
{
 foo: typeA,
 bar: typeB
}){...}
```

One would expect `T` to be inferred to:

```
{
 foo: **input A**
 bar: **input B**
}
```

So that `T['foo']` would equal the type of `input A` (and so `typeA` is inferred to be `input A's type`)

However, when I try out this code, I get an error that states:

> **Type '"foo"' cannot be used to index type 'T'.**

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: It seems like a confusing way to define type parameters. How do you intend to call your function? What do you want `T` to be?

Comment: The reason I defined parameters like this is because it becomes self documenting on the calling side.

e.g. instead of just func('foo','bar') it becomes: func({purposeA: 'foo', purposeB: 'bar'}). I don't really want T to be anything. But I do want to make sure `bar` matches the same type as `foo`. `T` is only an intermediary

Comment: If that's the case, why not `function foo<T>({ foo, bar } : { foo: T, bar: T }) {}`?

Comment: Because I'm hoping for `T` to be inferred so it doesn't need to be declared explicitly every time I use the function.

Comment: Hmm, it _is_ inferred this way. If you call `foo({ foo: 1, bar: })`, `bar` will have to be a `number`.

Comment: Ahh, I thought inference was based on parameter position. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Just to clarify, is type inference in Typescript based on the *first* instance that a type if declared? For example, in `func test<T>(foo: T, bar: T)`, the type is inferred from the `foo` param?

Comment: @user1543574 not quite as simple as fixing the generic by the first occurence: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoD4AUwccAXItgDSIBGAhgE5nYCUTA3gLABQii9KUEPSRE4Abm4BfbtwD0sxEXqIADvRgBbWrABu6RDCjIAFvTgB3NIlpIU9M8phgMKWgBNEcYDRROA5oj4AERBiABkiAAMzIgAvLiIYCh69NwQCBiIAB5xyOhQwUFU0WKIcgpKiGgANjB+xlDVAJ6I1ehWTukaKtow1G3ITSr6hohucOhgAORGAFYgmVBwULTVzYjpzlD0tE7knkhQxiiKMPSZDH4gGihgRtQgRsBObmjl1nyuaAi0-Sd+tzsMAgJm0YwmVnMcHoAGsAHRpDJGFqxPIYfBsaxkEKISRUTHUbGhSTMMRAA)